# Как в pandas стилизовать таблицу

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Я сделал так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_declaration) 
 
df=df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center', 'text_wrap': True})  
df.to_excel('./team.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Мой текст в таблице выровнялся по горизонтали. Я бы хотел его центрировать по вертикали, сделать перенос текста, и увеличить ширину и высоту. Как я это могу зделать?

Comment: Самый простой способ - использовать xlsxWriter - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: Сначало питон запросил скачать jinja2, а потом перестал сохранять нормально ексель файлы

Comment: Дополните вопрос скриншотом/текстом ошибки

Comment: Я использую функцию ```writer.sheets['Summary'].column_dimensions['A'].width = 15```  но она распространяется только на столбец А, А мне надо чтоб на все.  И как мне сделать перенос строки

Comment: Во первых звучит невероятно логично, что передав в `column_dimensions` только `'A'` действие распростронится только на А. Почитайте документацию, попробуйте указать `'A:Z'`. О каком переносе строки речь? Да и вообще, обсуждение таких вещей выходит за рамки вопроса.